# ¿Cuál es el sujeto y el objeto directo en la frase "Algo pasa a ella"? What is the subject and direct object of the sentence "Algo pasa a ella"?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, comparación-de-idiomas, sujeto

Actualmente estoy tomando clases de español. Encontré esta frase

> Algo pasa a ella.

en una clase cuando practicamos pronombres de objeto directo y objeto indirecto. El profesor me explicó que "ella" es objeto indirecto en esta frase y "algo" es objeto directo. Y podemos modificar la frase como "Le pasa algo".

Pero no entiendo nada. En inglés cuando se dice "Something happens to her", "something" es el sujeto y "her" es el objeto directo. Así que pienso que "algo" debe ser el sujeto y "ella" debe ser objeto directo y entonces debemos usar "la" en vez de "le" cuando modificar la frase. ¿Podrían ustedes explicarme esta frase y si estoy equivocado o no?

Answer (score 2):

Bueno ya me cansé de editar la respuesta pero cada vez que lo pienso de nuevo encuentro una nueva interpretación. Voy a considerar dos situaciones diferentes:

**1° CASO: ELLA RECIBE ALGO**

> (Él/ella) Algo pasa a ella.

El análisis sería:

- ’Él/ella’: sujeto
- ’algo’: complemento de régimen
- ‘pasa’: verbo
- ‘a ella’: objeto indirecto

No creo que haya mucho que explicar, en este caso *pasar* es **transitivo** y ‘a ella’ es un **objeto indirecto**. El reemplazo correcto es **le**. Notar que no puede omitirse ‘algo’ sin que la frase pierda sentido, sólo por esto no lo podemos considerar objeto directo.

Sin embargo, no es muy idiomático este uso del verbo, ya que en general se prefiere usar la siguiente frase con el verbo *dar*:

> (Él) Le da algo a ella.
> He gives something to her.

El único caso en el que pienso que puede sonar natural es en el fútbol, en ese caso sí usamos *pasar* con esta acepción:

> Él pasa la pelota a ella.

Conclusión: Si este era el sentido de la frase, tu profesor está en lo cierto. Tu problema fue una mala interpretación del verbo *pasar*—pero decile que de todas formas en la práctica nadie habla así.

**2° CASO: A ELLA LE PASA ALGO**

Esto es más interesante. Lo que había interpretado al comienzo es que quisiste referirte a:

> Algo **le** pasa a ella.
> Something happens to her.

Al contrario, cuando el verbo *pasar* se usa con la acepción de *acontecerle* u *ocurrirle* algo a alguien, entonces el mismo es **intransitivo** y por lo tanto [no admite ningún tipo de objeto](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/339535/do-intransitive-verbs-really-never-take-an-indirect-object). ‘A ella’ es simplemente un **sintagma preposicional**, y ‘le’ es el **complemento de régimen** ya que no es posible eliminarlo sin cambiar el sentido del verbo.

Algunos van a oponerse y van a sostener que ‘a ella’ es un objeto indirecto, extendiendo así la definición de objeto indirecto. Queda a tu merced (o la de tu profesor) elegir el criterio de clasificación de sintagmas que más te convenga. El análisis sintáctico no es un ‘invento’, sino que diversos autores han propuesto reglas basándose en los usos del idioma que los hablantes ya hacían. Es por eso que puede darse esta diferencia a la hora de clasificar.

Siguiendo la clasifiación más estándar y tradicional, el análisis queda:

- ‘Algo’ (*something*): sujeto
- ‘le’: complemento de régimen
- ‘pasa’ (*happens*): verbo
- ‘a ella’ (*to her*): sintagma preposicional

Conclusión: Si este era el sentido de la frase, se equivocó tu profesor con el análisis de ‘Algo’; y eliminar ‘a ella’ es una elipsis, no es el típico reemplazo de pronombre como sí ocurriría con los objetos indirectos.

Comment: My reading, as a non-native speaker, was your case 2. The first one seemed quite unnatural to me.

Comment: Así como la escribió la interpretación gramatical correcta es la 1° opción. Es válida, pero no suena muy natural. Por eso también me pasó que pensé que se refería a la 2°. El profesor probablemente haya pensado en la 1°

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada. Deje me escribir todo el ejemplo de la clase: "Lucía es siempre muy simpática pero cuando ayer vi a Lucía estaba un borde. Creo que pasa algo a ella". Así que, segunda frase debe significar "something happens to her", tu caso segundo.

Comment: @Gökhan Entonces te estabas refiriendo al segundo caso, pero en esta situación el verbo requiere que sea antepuesto el *le*. Lo correcto es: ‘Creo que algo le pasa a ella’. Además ‘estaba un borde’ no tiene ningún sentido quizá podría ser ‘estaba en un borde’, que tiene sentido sintáctico pero aún no tiene ninguna interpretación plausible. ¿Quizá quisite traducirlo como ‘estar en agonía’? Si tenés la frase en otro idioma pasala, sino no hay mucho más que se pueda hacer

Comment: @tac ya escribí la frase exactamente. No la traduzco de otra idioma, es como la veo en la presentación del profesor.

Comment: @Gökhan Por desgracia no tiene sentido. Tal vez quiso decir algo como ‘Lucía estaba en un precipicio’ y usó la palabra ‘borde’ como una mala traducción. Espero que te haya servido

Comment: @tac  supongo que quería usar esta definición: “borde adj. y com. Tosco, torpe, desagradable de trato”. Se puede decir que una persona es un borde

Comment: @Cerulean ¿... cuando ayer vi a Lucía *era un borde*??? ¿Y qué, ya no es más? En todo caso sería ‘cuando vi a Lucía fue un borde conmigo’, que ni siquiera sé si es correcto ese uso